# SQL query to pivot a column using MERGE or another faster ways without pivot table

Tags: sql-server, merge, pivot

I have the following table:

```
paymentgateway           status
--------------           --------
1                         1
2                         2
3                         1
2                         3
2                         3
.                         .
.                         .
.                         .
```

I am trying to write an SQL query to give the following result:

```
paymentgetways              status1         status2        status3
 --------------              ------         -------        --------
      1                        1               0              1
      2                        0               1              2
      3                        1               0              0
      .
      .
      .
```

How can I modify my query to give the correct presentation? i dont want to use case when ,Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the `static pivot query`, change this to `dynamic` based on your needs. Ref [Dynamic PIVOT in Sql Server](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/)

```
DECLARE @Test AS TABLE(paymentgateway int, status int)

insert into @Test VALUES(1,1)
insert into @Test VALUES(2,2)
insert into @Test VALUES(3,1)
insert into @Test VALUES(2,3)
insert into @Test VALUES(2,3)

SELECT paymentgateway, [1] AS status1, [2] AS status2, [3] AS status3 FROm @Test
PIVOT (COUNT(Status) FOR Status IN ([1], [2], [3])) AS A
```

Comment: tanks but i have to use merge table or another ways to solve it